# How to prepare magazine for print

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design

I would like to prepare brochure/magazine for printing, it should have 10 pages (exluding the front page and the one on the back), and I would like to have it in this layout: (check photos pls):

[image]

[image]

So the page is A4 size, and 2 pages should be next to each other (except the front and back page) and it is printed on A3 sized paper, which are subsequently folded/bent. There have to be bleeds, because the photo and yellow bar which should end at the edge.

How can this be done? I mean, I successfully prepared in Illustrator a 10 single-page A4 papers with bleeds, but... it would not be folded then, just associated with tailstock or something like that, no?

Thank you very much for your help and time! :-) Have a nice Saturday

Comment: Well for a start you can't have 10 pages (unless you want 2 blank pages). You need multiples of 4 (there are 4 pages per sheet).

Comment: Are you planning to literally print this yourself, or is it to be sent off to a professional company? If the latter, ask them. (And if they ask for a properly imposed document - never mind what that means, run away and find another printer ...)

Comment: @RadLexus Why would the printer asking for impositions be a problem? The shop where I worked had a pre-press department and always sent the printer files in imposition spreads.

Comment: Hire a designer. The math Cai gave you 10-12 will be the least of your problems.

Comment: @Cai, in a way, he's right. It's 10 pages of content, plus a cover and back cover. Normal people don't consider a cover or back cover to be pages, they think of them as... cover and back cover. For them, the contents are the pages.

Comment: @Confused um maybe, apart from the fact that OP originally said the exact opposite

Comment: @Cai there's more than a few ways Johny is struggling to express himself and his question. Probably frustrated with his predicament. An empathetic, caring and considerate reading of his endeavours isn't asking too much.

Comment: @Confused I have no idea what you're getting at. My comment was a genuine and important piece of information—you simply removed the problem from the question, with no explanation or clarification from OP that that was their intention.

Comment: You've ignored the bigger problems in favour of being pedantic. I imagine you can see he's asking: how do I layout this set of A4 pages, regardless their number, so they can be folded and bound from A3 paper? What do printers expect from me in this situation? Are there ways to do this in Illustrator or Indesign with specific layouts? How is this normally done? The problem, as you well know, is going from A4 uniques to A3 with folds, and dealing with a printer's expectations and desires. Johny might not have asked it perfectly, but the context makes it clear where and why he's struggling.

Comment: @Confused that's why I commented instead of answering. I wasn't being pedantic at all, I was making an important point—which you just corrected in the question instead (which you really shouldn't do)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are printing this with an outside provider, you should be asking them because they will probably need these in a specific way. Generally what i would assume you will have to export your inner pages as single A4 pages and then separately export your covers (front and back) as A3 (most likely a centimeter less wide than A3, so it can bend properly). But all of this should be discussed with the printing company, especially if your experience is limited.

Comment: @Lucian has this nailed. It's going to be upto the printshop how they help you with this. Some will handle all layout requirements for you, no matter how far off you are from their desired file construction. Others will be pedantic, and there's everything in between. Buying your printer beers and pizzas (or local equivalents) is some of the most remarkably effective money you can spend.

Answer (score 1):

the page is A4 size, and 2 pages should be next to each other?

this is not possible in the centre pinning process, you need to work as a form printing on 4 ups. and the total number of pages including the cover and the back cover should be multiple of 4. that means u should either have 8 pages or 12 pages including the cover and back cover. centre pinning is not possible if you want to have pages side by side.